# How to handle Empty String value for Decimal data type while reading from a file within the Dataframe in Spark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to read data from a csv file using dataframe by passing a schema. For few columns the data is coming as empty string whose corresponding dataype is double. So when I try to read the file, whenever the data is empty string for those columns, the whole file content is coming as null and I'm unable to read the content of file.

eg : test.csv

```
col1,col2,5.45, ,xyz
(string,string,decimal,decimal,string)
```

So when I try to read the file

```
 val df = spark.read.option("header", false).schema(tblschema).csv("path/test.csv")
df.show()
```

all columns are with null values
null,null,null,null,null

Is there any way to read the file content for double/decimal datatype columns when its passing emptystring or blank values?

Comment: how was your schema `tblschema` defined?

Comment: I have a function which I pass the table structure.I'm able to read data when there is no emply string or blank values or If convert the doubletype to string type.